# What steps are needed to start angular.js in ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, webapps

I am a newbie in webapp development and Ibuntu. I tried to use yeoman to start angularjs. After I follow 3 step to use yeoman to start angular in this web: http://yeoman.io/codelab/review-generated-files.html , I don't understand the step 4. What should I do to open scaffolded directory?

Thank you for your answer guys

Comment: It is completely unclear what your problem is or where you got stuck or what you did already.

Comment: I think he did steps 1, 2, & 3 in the link provided but got stuck on step 4 (which is where the link takes you to).

Comment: oh, i am sorry, this is the link where i stuck http://yeoman.io/codelab/review-generated-files.html

Answer (score 0):

In step 4 you should observe "mytodo" directory. Compare if the same files and directories exist.
To start GUI file manager you can execute command "nautilus" or "xdd-open ." in terminal as you did in step 3 with command "yo".

In the screen shot you see the "Sublime Text" editor with turned on navigation sidebar.

Comment: but  mytodo folder is empty, do you think it fine or not?

Comment: Then let's move to step 3. To test if step 3 is OK run following command: 
`yo --version`
This command should print version of Yeoman. For example "1.4.8" or similar.

Comment: oke, i found i have angulat version 1.4.8, then what command line to start angular?

Comment: Now we know web application generation tool is installed. To generate angular application you should follow this tutorial from step 3:
`cd ~/mytodo && yo` or `cd ~/mytodo && yo angular`.  There must be no error messages. When the directory 'mytodo' will have some files and folder we can go to step 5 and start Angular generated application.

Comment: Oke, i have done that, but no one file or folder installed.

Comment: npm WARN EPEERINVALID grunt-karma@0.12.1 requires a peer of karma@^0.13.0 || >= 0.14.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-jasmine@0.3.6 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.1 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.1 requires a peer of phantomjs@>=1.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON velteraniard@0.0.0 No license field.